# headset appears with input devices but not output

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headset

I am connecting a headset to my machine but it is not showing up with output devices even though the headset mic exist between input devices.
I had a similar issue before on another machine & it was solved by adding two lines to this file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` :

```
options snd-hda-intel position fix=1
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

but the same solution did not work.
I also tried to restart pulseaudio

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

then I tried reloading alsa

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

And the solutions in this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645000.
but none of them worked for me.
in my other machine there is a dialog that shows up every time I connect an audio device, but I dont see it on this one.

NOTE: I have windows 11 on the same machine and the headset is working on it perfectly.

**UPDATE: I installed pipewire then reboot, connected my headset & now there are not any devices inside sound settings**.
[sound settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/755AS.png)

I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37589/alsa-permissions/37609#37609) but also did not work for me.

**UPDATE 2:** Now, I can see [two input devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtQiD.png) in pavucontrol & sound settings, when I choose the internal mic, I can record audio & hear sounds
but when I choose the other choice (microphone) I can still record audio but can't hear anything.

Comment: we have switched to `pipewire` Care to give that a go? It has better support for and more features than PA  https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/enable-pipewire-audio-service-ubuntu-21-04/

Comment: I tried installing pipewire & updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some kind of a workaround.

```
options snd-hda-intel position fix=1
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

I added these two lines in the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
& with the help of this command `hdajackretask`, chose show unconnected pins then I overrode two options (I think they are called pins).
well, It works but I have to choose headphone & microphone manually every time I connect my headset.
If someone have a better solution, please tell me.